# Create country boundary mask on SpatRaster file using terra and ggplot in R

Tags: raster, shapefile, mapping, terra, ggplot

I'd like to create a map of sea surface temperature displaying my countries of interest as a mask, using terra and ggplot.

I've got a SpatRaster of sea surface temperature and a shapefile object that contains the boundaries of a country of interest. I'd like to plot a box showing the temperature values of the ocean combined with a mask of the country, so wherever inside the polygons (inland) the raster image should be masked and contain no values, whereas I want to display watever is classed as water that it is outside of the polygon boundaries.

I've managed to do the inverse operation so only pixels that fallsinside of the country or in a cell where there is a boundary are displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is some code I used:

```
Ishp <- read_sf("D:Indonesia_Shoreline.shp")
v <- vect(Ishp)
v <- project(v,SST_Indonesia)
plot(mask(crop(SST_Indonesia[[2]],v),v))
plot(v, add = T)
```